# In Java: Could not find the main class

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

When I wrote a standalone client and tried to execute it, 
it's giving me the following errors:

Running in Windows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestClient
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: TestClient.  Program will exit.
```

This is in Linux

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestClient (wrong name: com/tata/bayer/service/TestClient)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: TestClient.  Program will exit.
```

Now i am getting

```
C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\webapps\tkweb-ws-12.0\WEB-INF\classes\com>java com.tata.bayer.service.TestClient
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tata/bayer/service/TestClient
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tata.bayer.service.TestClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: com.tata.bayer.service.TestClient  Program will exit.
```

Comment: What command are you using to run them, what package definition did you have in the code, and what CLASSPATH do you have?

Comment: Where is your compiled `TestClient.class` file?

Comment: working in tcs with bayer client ? please mask your company packages,as it might violate your company policies.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you should be running

```
java com.tata.bayer.service.TestClient
```

from a directory containing "com", with an appropriate directory hierarchy eventually leading to `TestClient.class`.

You haven't shown whether you're compiling this code yourself or whether it's been given to you. If you *are* compiling it yourself, you should usually organize the source code so that it reflects the package structure too. So you might run:

```
javac com/tata/bayer/service/*.java
java com.tata.bayer.service.TestClient
```

Or maybe:

```
# Keep source and class files separate...
javac -d bin com/tata/bayer/service/*.java
java -classpath bin com.tata.bayer.service.TestClient
```

If that doesn't help, please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use `com/tata/bayer/service/TestClient` and not `TestClient`. Try using the full path.